# Java example of joining 2 CSV files based on common column

Tags: java, csv

I have 2 CSV file with the following content.

File 1

```
Id, Name, last name, city
1,peter,green,newyork
2,sam,red,londan
```

File 2

```
Id,Movie,Famous move
1,Hulk,punch
2,Ironman,taking the stone.
```

File after joining file1 and file2

File

```
Id, Name, last name, city,Movie,Famous move
1,peter,green,newyork,Hulk,punch
2,sam,red,london,Ironman,taking the stone
```

How I can join this 2 CSV file based on same column in java.

Any help will be appreciated.

Can anyone help how to achieve this in java. In python it is a 5 line code using PANDAS Lib.

Comment: You will first have to load the contents of your files into your program, for example by using one of the techniques described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-csv-file-array) and then perform a join operation using one of the algorithms described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Join_algorithms)

Comment: Is this a one-off type of thing or does an application need to do this? Honestly if it's one off, i'd load the CSV's into a db locally, do the join there and export the results as a CSV. If you do need to keep it in java, you could look at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hash_join#Java